# IIS 7.5 getting one session variable in ASP.Net, but not a second one

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7.5, session-variables

I have an ASP.Net app (.Net 4, C#, web forms, pointed to a production SQL box) that runs beautifully in Visual Studio, but when loaded onto an IIS Server hosted on the same Windows 7 box, it refuses to load a second session variable. In VS debug, it comes up and shows the name of the person logged into the app, normally getting it from Active Directory, but I do provide an option for another AD user to login. (Using ASP.Net's login controls is not really feasible.)

The problem is I cannot debug this on the production server, but since it works in Visual Studio, debug will not reveal anything. Any thoughts on what needs to be changed on IIS or in web.config? I've included the imports for the code behind.

At my wit's end with this one and about ready to go back to good ol' query strings, even though that'll be less secure and look like an Amazon.com link. Help.

Tom Hottle

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Configuration;


namespace ITIncidentMgt
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private SqlConnection conn;
        private string dbConnect =
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AssetMgtString"].ConnectionString;
    private string SQL;
    private string sErr;
    private string hello;
    private string user_name;
    private int userID;
    private string user;
    private string field;
    private string val;
    private string add;
    private string wHere = " WHERE ";


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            user_name = Environment.UserName;
            if (DAC.OpenSqlConnection(ref conn, dbConnect, out sErr))
            {
                if (Session["u"] == null)
                {

                    SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '" + user_name + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        userID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["UserID"]);
                        user = dr["DisplayName"].ToString();
                    }
                    dr.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    Session["u"] = userID;
                    Session["n"] = user;
                }
                else
                {
                    userID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["u"]);
                    user = Session["n"].ToString();
                }
                hello = "Welcome, " + user + ".";
                lblHello.Text = hello;
```

Comment: If Session["u"] is --> not null <--, Session["n"] will never get set, therefore "user" will not get set.

Answer (score 0):

What kd7 says. Session["u"] will staty as not-null 'forever' after a login because you aren't using asp.net login & logout. 
The custom logout functionality you need to go with your custom login would be something like 
    protected void OnLogoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        session["u"]=null;
        session["n"]=null;
    }
If your IIS server has session set to 20mins, then you should experience 'auto-logout' after 20mins.

Comment: (Sorry. I didn't see kd7's comment) I see I need to add to my original explanation. The only way Session ["u"] can be set is if it goes through a process that also calls Session["n"]. The only way Session["u"] can be null is if this is the first time the user has logged in. "Else" assumes (and performs like this in VS) that the first block of code has already been performed during the session.

What happens on the IIS server that doesn't happen in VS is that neither block sees "n", only "u" for some reason. "n" appears in the label. So it's not setting it in either block.

Nice and muddy, eh?

Comment: Incidentally, as I said in a since-deleted comment, session timeout is set for 30 minutes.

In the meantime, if I can get this working on a Win 2K8 install instead of the local box, I might have something more useful to send back.

Comment: Fair point. Okay, next efforts: (1) Is it possible that in production dr["DisplayName"].ToString() is null? (2) if you can't debug, can you log? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307024 might be the least-code way of logging. WARNING the gotcha with it is, that the thread in production that tries to call EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource,sLog) must have permissions to write to the registry otherwise it crashes. Best solved by logging in as admin and manually creating the event source

Comment: Actually, I figure out a way to debug by putting the line setting session["n"] in an if-else wrapper and having it throw an error if the original variable was null or an empty string. Just to make sure I'm not insane (at least on this point), I verified I wasn't pulling a display name that accidentally got deleted. (I hope not. It's not just my name, but that kind of deletion would gum up another app that's otherwise working.) Sure enough, in VS, it pulls both fields. On IIS, just the first one. I'm going to check your link and spend some quality time on Google. Inglorious results later today.

Comment: Well, it's clearly a problem pulling the display name from the table. I split the query in two as a trouble shooting method, having it just pull the display name by itself. Ran it in VS, worked. In IIS, it absolutely refuses to pull that field. Here's where it gets really weird: It pulls that field in another query two blocks later to populate a dropdown list with that same field. I'm suspecting a permissions or connection issue, but that sounds a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

And we have it cracked. The offending line is this one:

user_name = Environment.UserName;

In Visual Studio, that's whoever's logged into the computer. On IIS, it's System. And there is a System in the User table this draws from, but System has no display name. No display name means you're pulling a null value, which in turn makes this application very sad and throw one of those lovely earthtone ASP.Net screens we all enjoy.

Fortunately, this has happened in this particular enterprise before, so the solution is in production on another app. Or I can just make everyone log in manually.

How I found it: I wrote a temporary label called lblTest and set lblTest.Text = user_name in page load.

Thanks all for the input. Naturally, it's one of those "I shoulda known better" bugs.